# The Question is regarding setting up the new workspace in the bashrc file

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had created catkin_ws before and now i have another workspace called my_ws. I have changed the path in the bashrc file to the my_ws and yet whenever i type roscd, it takes me to catkin_ws. Why is that and what needs to be done in order to resolve the issue?

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
#source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
#source /home/yash/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
source ~/my_ws/devel/setup.bash
source /home/yash/my_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320844/the-question-is-regarding-setting-up-the-new-workspace-in-the-bashrc-file./) by [Yash](https://answers.ros.org/users/40819/yash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

your .bashrc has some duplicates.
It should probaly look something like

```
...
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source ~/my_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

As to why roscd still takes you to your old ws, this would happen if you are not using a terminal loaded without the changes in place.  So for the changes you made to take effect you will need to reload .bashrc.

Either open a new terminal and try there.

Or type `exec bash` into the already open terminal to reload .bashrc.

---

Originally posted by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) with karma: 591 on 2019-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1